# using $and with $match in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, match

I am trying to use the following query in MongoDB but it is not working.

```
  db.test.aggregate(
    $match: {
      $and: [
        type: { $in: ["TOYS"] },
        type: { $nin: ["BARBIE"] },
        time: { $lt: ISODate("2013-12-09T00:00:00Z") }
      ]
    }
  })
```

It says invalid character ":".

Is it possible to use $and with $match? I have seen an example on this forum of $or with $match so I presumed this is possible.

Thank you in advance for your help and guidance.

Comment: The documentation is here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gather that I do not need to use $and since it is implied in the query?

Comment: This is a query that works perfectly without aggregation framework, use a regular find

Comment: I agree with Maximiliano Rios, read this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Why suggest him to use something else, instead of helping to solve his problem? Maybe what we see is only a tiny part of his full aggregation?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

> $and with $match works just fine.

You have syntax errors in your query. Try this.

```
db.test.aggregate([
                   { 
                     $match: {
                          $and: [ 
                              {type: {$in: ["TOYS"]}}, 
                              {type: {$nin: ["BARBIE"]}}, 
                              {time: {$lt:ISODate("2013-12-09T00:00:00Z")}}
                          ]
                     }
                   }
                  ])
```

And for what you are trying to do, you do not need an `$and`.

Comment: Hi Ajai.....thanks for the correction. And yes I found out that $and is not required. Thank you to all for helping me out.

Comment: Isn't the use `$and` redundant in this case? At least in MongoDB 3.2+ it seems to be.

Comment: Yes. $and is redundant here.We have it to answer the question: `Is it possible to use $and with $match?`

Comment: I don't think `$and` is entirely redundant within `$match`... Maybe in the most simple cases... First I tried two separate `$expr` conditions directly within `$match`, but was not getting the proper result... Had to add the `$and` in order to combine the comparisons properly (version 3.6.2).

Comment: In the case where you build the matching expression sequentially and have several conditions on the same parameter, using $and in the $match expression can be pretty convenient.

Answer (score 9):

```
{
  $match: {
    $or:[
      {'sender':sender, 'recipient':recipient},
      {'recipient':sender,'sender':recipient}
    ]
  }
}
```

using $or

Answer (score 8):

```
db.test.find( {$and: [ {"type": {$in: ["TOYS"]}}, 
                       {"type": {$nin: ["BARBIE"]}}, 
                       {"time": {$lt:ISODate("2013-12-09T00:00:00Z")}}
                     ]
})
```

AND works with FIND, receives an array of matches (but it's not a match instruction)
Aggregation framework is for something completely different, it's like the word says, for aggregating (count, sum, avg, and so worth grouping or unwinding, etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Maximiliano. I used an aggregation because I needed to group by userID after matching these records. Sorry for giving an incomplete picture of the problem. So I gather $and is not possible with aggregation then....

Comment: You can use $and with aggregation but you don't have to write it, and is implicit using different filters, in fact you can pipe those filters in case one of them needs a different solution.

Comment: `$match` takes `{ <query> }`. That means, it can take `$and` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

example of $lookup then $match

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$user"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "privacy.mode": {
            "$gt": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "user.privacy.mode": {
            "$gt": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
``
```