# MongoDB (3.0) Aggregation: Several matches vs One match with multiple items

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on a project that requires me to create a dynamic MongoDB query on the fly based on a lot of matches (probably a potential of 100). On top of creating the proper indexes I was wondering if it mattered how I built the matches into the pipeline. Based on the following example, does one of these examples perform differently or better than the other?

I assume Example 2 would widdle down the result set but be more calls? Maybe that is what Example 1 is doing behind the scenes?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Example 1**

```
db.Test.aggregate(
[     
   { $match: { item1: 'foo1', item2: 'foo2', item3: 'foo3' } }
])
```

vs

**Example 2**

```
db.Test.aggregate(
[     
   { $match: { item1: 'foo1' } },
   { $match: { item2: 'foo2' } },
   { $match: { item3: 'foo3' } }
])
```

*I doubt it matter for this question but if relevant I will be using the C# driver for my implementation.*

Comment: Interesting question...have you managed to find and answer?

Comment: I would also be curious to know!

Answer (score 13):

I found the following information in [MongoDB's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#match-match-coalescence):

> ## `$match` + `$match` Coalescence
>
> When a `$match` immediately follows another `$match`, the two stages can coalesce into a single $match combining the conditions with an `$and`. For example, a pipeline contains the following sequence:
>
> ```
> { $match: { year: 2014 } },
> { $match: { status: "A" } }
> ```
>
> Then the second $match stage can coalesce into the first $match stage and result in a single $match stage:
>
> ```
> { $match: { $and: [ { "year" : 2014 }, { "status" : "A" } ] } }
> ```

From this I can say that using several `$match` in a row is the same as using a single `$match` with multiple fields.

I am unsure however why does the optimization engine add a `$and` operator here. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469712/using-and-with-match-in-mongodb#answer-20470944) it shouldn't be necessary, therefore I think it can be ignored. Somebody can confirm?

Comment: I also assumed that $and was implied anyways so it does seem unnecessary, but there might be another reason behind it

Comment: The reason is because the same field can appear in two or more $match stages. A Bson (Json, Map,...) can not have duplicate keys, they are silently ignored.

Answer (score 5):

I was wondering the same thing today and stumbled on the answer of Romain. Though I wanted to see this for myself, which can easily be done using an explain on both aggregates;

```
db.verpakking.explain().aggregate([
    { "$match": {type: "VERPAKT"} },
    { "$match": {ras: "CherryStar"} },
]);
```

Which results in the following output:

```
{
  "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {
          "$and" : [
            {
              "type" : "VERPAKT"
            },
            {
              "ras" : "CherryStar"
            }
          ]
        },
        "queryPlanner" : {
          "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1),
          "namespace" : "denberk.verpakking",
          "indexFilterSet" : false,
          "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
              {
                "ras" : {
                  "$eq" : "CherryStar"
                }
              },
              {
                "type" : {
                  "$eq" : "VERPAKT"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
              "$and" : [
                {
                  "ras" : {
                    "$eq" : "CherryStar"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "type" : {
                    "$eq" : "VERPAKT"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
          },
          "rejectedPlans" : [

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

While

```
db.verpakking.explain().aggregate([
{ "$match": {type: "VERPAKT", ras: "CherryStar"} },
]);
```

Results in output:

```
{
  "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {
          "type" : "VERPAKT",
          "ras" : "CherryStar"
        },
        "queryPlanner" : {
          "plannerVersion" : NumberInt(1),
          "namespace" : "denberk.verpakking",
          "indexFilterSet" : false,
          "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
              {
                "ras" : {
                  "$eq" : "CherryStar"
                }
              },
              {
                "type" : {
                  "$eq" : "VERPAKT"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
              "$and" : [
                {
                  "ras" : {
                    "$eq" : "CherryStar"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "type" : {
                    "$eq" : "VERPAKT"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
          },
          "rejectedPlans" : [

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

As you can see this is exactly the same, except for the "query" portion (which is normal, since our query **was** different). This proves that whether you use two separate consecutive $match-pipelines or one combined $match-pipeline, the parsed query will be exactly the same.