# How to group documents by week in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How do i calculate the total hours spend by each user on the basis of week and my **week start from Friday to Thursday**.

**Records**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a69cd076b2beec65fa900e9"),
  "clock_date" : ISODate("2018-01-13T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "clock_in_time" : "10:40:53",
  "clock_out_time" : "12:40:53", 
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a69cd076b2beec65fa900e9"),
  "clock_date" : ISODate("2018-01-12T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "clock_in_time" : "10:00:53",
  "clock_out_time" : "10:40:53", 
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a69cd076b2beec65fa900e9"),
  "clock_date" : ISODate("2018-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "clock_in_time" : "10:20:00",
  "clock_out_time" : "12:40:53", 
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a69cd076b2beec65fa900e9"),
  "clock_date" : ISODate("2018-01-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
  "clock_in_time" : "10:40:53",
  "clock_out_time" : "11:40:53", 
},
```

**Result to be like**

```
 {
  week:'Jan 05, 2018 to Jan 11, 2018'
  totalhourse : 4
 },
 {
  week:'Jan 12, 2018 to Jan 18, 2018'
  totalhourse : 2:23
 },
```

.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Your week starts from Friday to Tuesday so It ignores Wednesday and Thursday ?

Comment: sorry it will be Thursday

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the total hours with this schema is going to be tough and we should have a lot of calculations, since you have captured the time in and time out as strings. To find the difference we need to segregate `hours:minutes:seconds` and then we have to find the difference.

```
"clock_in_time" : "10:40:53",
"clock_out_time" : "12:40:53",
```

Alternatively you can modify your schema to capture the in time and out time as Date with time stamp.

```
"clock_in_time" : ISODate("2018-01-13T10:40:53.123+05:30"),
"clock_out_time" : ISODate("2018-01-13T12:40:53.121+05:30"),
```

If this modification is done then you can use aggregation pipeline to get the desired result

In aggregation pipeline first

- Use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and $and to filter the documents within the date
  range(here you can feed in week start date and week end date)
- then use [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) with [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Please note this query will give you only one week's result at a time

References:

[Subtracting time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369419/how-to-subtract-two-date-time-in-mongodb)

[$match with $and operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469712/using-and-with-match-in-mongodb)